# Use object included from global <script> tag inside React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

I am trying to add paypal [button](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) using React.

According to paypals dev [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/single-page-app/) i need to include

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"></script>
```

in `<head></head>` in `index.html` tag and then use

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
const PayPalButton = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });
function YourComponent() {
  const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            value: "0.01",
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  };
  const onApprove = (data, actions) => {
    return actions.order.capture();
  };
  return (
    <PayPalButton
      createOrder={(data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)}
      onApprove={(data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)}
    />
  );
}
```

However
`const PayPalButton = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", {React, ReactDOM});`

line throws error

`'paypal' is not defined  no-undef`

It the object included from external `<script>` isn't loaded. How can i load load object from external `<script>` into React component then?

Comment: `window.paypal.whatever`. But seriously: don't confuse a *linter warning* with an *actual error*. Your code should work fine as is. If the linter warning blocks a build pipeline or something you can suppress it with a directive comment or use the global window object explicitly.

Comment: it does not compile with this error

Comment: @Darlyn — See Jared's previous comment about overriding your linter.

Comment: @Quentin TBF I edited that in about the same time he was posting that.

Comment: @JaredSmith yea using window... worked, can u post the comment as answer with way how to suppress the linter? Couldnt find any answer to my question before posting it and i am pretty sure lot of ppl who works in react/js once a year will stumble across this problem just like me

Comment: @Darlyn done, glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to square that circle:

```js
const PayPalButton = window.paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });
```

Remember that in Javascript global variables are also properties of the global object (`window` in the browser). I actually like doing this for globals, because it makes it very clear in the code that this thing is a global variable rather than reading it and going "WTF where did that come from?".

You can also (assuming ESLint) suppress the lint warning directly (NOT recommended):

```js
// eslint-disable-line no-undef
const PayPalButton = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });
```